# Does tensorflow recompute these values?

Tags: tensorflow

If I call `x,y = sess.run([X,f(X)])`, is `X` computed once or twice? I'm asking because in my case the value of `X` is not deterministic, and it's necessary that `f` be evaluated on the same 'instance' of `X`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure that `f` uses the current `X` you can set up dependencies.

```
with tf.control_dependencies([X]):
    y = f(X)
x, y_ = sess.run([X, y])
```

Answer (score 0):

It will only compute it once.  It would not make sense if it recomputed the dependent variables.  Just about all variables in a tensorflow model are dependent on one another.